# Ruby hash to array convert

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have something like this:

```
[#TrajectoryMeasurement depth: 0, move_e: 234>,
#TrajectoryMeasurement depth: 1475, move_e: 123>]
```

How to convert it to:

```
[[0, 234], [1475,123]]
```

Comment: This is not a Hash. This is an array of objects.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl It is neither. It is not a valid Ruby code.

Comment: @sawa: I'll not argue, I'm just guessing as the notation seems broken to me. Is it a normal dump of some construct?

Comment: @plewas, does TrajectoryMeasurement respond to methods depth and move_e?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I checked the source of the OP's original posting. I don't think the mess is because of interaction with the markup. The OP simply posted invalid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an array of objects as I suspect you can use the #collect method on Array:

```
array = [#TrajectoryMeasurement depth: 0, move_e: 234>,
#TrajectoryMeasurement depth: 1475, move_e: 123>]

array.collect { |x| [x.depth, x.move_e] }
# => [[0, 234], [1475, 123]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you really had a hash, all you need is calling .to_a to get exactly what you asked for.

> {a:1, b:1}.to_a
>    => [[:a, 1], [:b, 1]]

Alas, as it was said before, it wouldn't see, what you have there is a Hash, unless that's an ad-hoc representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your hash you might also want to have a look at .flatten.